# How can I reverse an upvote which I didn't realize I had already voted on?

Tags: support, voting

I accidentally upvoted a comment and a box appeared.  (Since I don't keep a ledger of my votes.) How can I erase the errant vote?

I was afraid to hit the flag icon.  Is there a way to tell when I have already voted?

Comment: (NEW UPVOTE ICON) I like the new "colored" arrow for quick observation! It give quick knowledge of past actions.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

To answer both your questions - an upvoted comment has a highlighted up arrowhead, and clicking on it again gives you a prompt asking you if you want to undo an upvote. You can only undo it once though.

Comment: This is no longer possible once one reloads the page - it only works on the same page load as the one where one upvoted the comment.